# Problems with printing locations into console in Xcode 8, ios 10.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cllocationmanager

I got stack with such issue, trying to make a simple app, using CoreLocation.
I wrote all necessary keys into info.plist

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        print (locations)
    }

}
```

However, application doesn't write anything to console. Are there any special moments, working with location is ios 10?

Comment: Are you sure the permission is enabled, did you check the settings for permissions?

Comment: well, firstly, I decided to run without writing any information into info.plist. So, app told me, that I'm trying to access restricted data and I need to ask for permission. After that, I wrote NSLocationAlwaysUasgeDescription and NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription keys.